# why mongoose doesn't change mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

my mongdb is started by:  sudo mongod --port 27111

but my  mongoose code() doesnt work on mongodb, nothing in mongodb changed 
from the mongo shell point of view.

$mongo 127.0.0.1:27111/foo                                                                                                              -- INSERT --
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27111/foo

> show dbs
>   local   0.078125GB
>   show dbs
>   local   0.078125GB

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db       = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27111/foo');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Tasks = new Schema({
  project: String,
  description: String,
});
mongoose.model('Task', Tasks);

var Task =mongoose.model('Task');

var task = new Task();     
task.project = 'bikeshed';
task.description = 'paint the bideshed red.';
task.save(function(err){   //save
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log('Task saved');
});


//搜索文档
Task.find({"project": 'bikeshed'}, function(err, tasks) {
  for (var i = 0 ; i < task.length ; i++) {
    console.log('--------------ID:' + tasks[i]._id);
  }
});

mongoose.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `mongoose.createConnection`, use `mongoose.connect`

```
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27111/foo');
```